# How to make a select sortable?

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I trying to make a select sortable but not having much luck

http://jsfiddle.net/ajcppmod/DGTG7/6/

```
<div class="sortable">
    <select>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
      <option>D</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
</div>

$('.sortable').sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable",

});
```

Is the select swallowing the mouse event. I'm pretty new to JS!

Thanks
AJ

Comment: if this is whole of your code it cannot work, as it throws a lot of errors. I don't know how you are familiar with js debugers (e.g F12 -> console under chrome) If you ask a little bit more specyfied question we will be more able to help you

Comment: Yes apologies about that. Should load with any errors now. I would like to be able to change the ordering of the dropdown select widgets (not the items within the dropdown) using drag and drop. I think the fact that the select responds to click events is interfering with the sortable draggable functionality. Any clues?

Comment: First if you want to reffer to the element by its class you need to use '.' instead of '#' eg '.classofelement' also maybe little workaround for your question. In this example you can move them using labels http://jsfiddle.net/DGTG7/7/

Comment: you are declaring a sortable and trying to connect it with itself ??? Not sure what do you want here